# Allow the draggable content exceed but not within the parent boundary in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable

I am using Jquery ui and it provide a function for me to make draggable content. It has an option 'containment' that force the draggable item move within the box.

However, for my case, the content (image) must exceed the screen , how can I force it not to drag inside the screen?

Thanks

```
$("#popup").draggable({
    addClasses:true,
    scrollSpeed: "200",
    containment: "parent",
    //appendTo: "body",
    helper: function(){
        // Create an invisible div as the helper. It will move and
        // follow the cursor as usual.
        return $('<div></div>').css('opacity',0);
    },
    drag: function(event, ui){
        // During dragging, animate the original object to
        // follow the invisible helper with custom easing.
        var p = ui.helper.position();
        $(this).stop().animate({
            top: p.top,
            left: p.left
        },1000,'easeOutCirc');
    }
});
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for your problem?